# Changing .exe icon and get error message: python.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, py2exe

Python.exe has stopped working during the compilation with py2exe. I used the following command to change the icon for my .exe python script, but python.exe hang and stopped working.

```
setup(
      console = [
      {
        "script": "CreateFile.py",                 
        "icon_resources": [(1, "Capture.ico")]     
      }
     ]
)
```

It hangs after this line in cmd prompt:
*** copy extensions** 
 **copy dlls ***
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run_w.exe -> C:\Users\PycharmProjects\exercise1\dist\CreateFile.exe

I have gone through many forum threads and tried many ways but still couldn't figure out why the hang is happening. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why is there a "1" in
[(1, "Capture.ico")]

Comment: i should have coment this instead od posting it as answer ,sorry